# How do I write a bash script that pulls from a branch before pushing to it?

Tags: bash, git

I'm a bash noob and am writing a pre-push Git hook to make it so that every time I want to push to branch "red", I pull from "red" first.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
branch_to_be_pushed_to=$(git symbolic-ref i_d_f_k)

if [ "$(branch_to_be_pushed_to)" = "red" ] 
        then
        echo "You are attempting to push to red. Pulling from red..."
        (git pull origin red)
fi

exit 0
```

What I'm looking for is how to get the value for "branch_to_be_pushed_to" and how to check if that value is equal to the remote branch "red". Looking for help on general syntax in this script as well if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep that site bookmarked. Any thoughts on how to get the "branch to be pushed to"?

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to replace `$(branch_to_be_pushed_to)` (command substitution) with `$branch_to_be_pushed_to` (variable).

Comment: `$(branch_to_be_pushed_to)` executes a command named `branch_to_be_pushed_to`. You should have received an error message! Testing the strings for equality is done by `[[ $branch_to_be_pushed_to == red ]]`.

Comment: Clarification needed: do you want to trigger your script when you push red or when you push _to_ red? `git push origin red:blue` vs. `git push origin blue:red`; which operation should trigger your hook action?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not going to work. From [Git's pre-push template](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample) (emphasis mine):

> An example hook script to verify what is about to be pushed.  Called by "git
> push" *after it has checked the remote status*, but before anything has been
> pushed.  If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.

In other words: if you would need to pull first, the pre-push script is never called since the branch would have never been pushed anyway based on the remote status. The script is only called for branches that actually can be pushed to the remote.

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a different solution to cover your use case.

Comment: Also what [the pre-push hook docs themselves](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) say. It's an opportunity to reject the operation, not to alter what it does. An operation as different as what OP wants isn't just a push any more and shouldn't masquerade as one.